# Configuring Shrew VPN to access Linksys RV082/RV042

Tags: vpn, shrew

Does anyone know how to successfully configure Shrew VPN to access a Linksys RV082 or RV042 over IPsec? Below is the error that I receive when I have configured our RV082 as specified in the [Shrew Linksys How To Guide](http://www.shrew.net/support/wiki/HowtoLinksys):

[image: Shrew Linksys VPN Error]

Comment: Regarding the policy violation, do you have any other router settings that may be blocking the connection?

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent tutorial for connecting Shrew to an RV0xx at http://www.shrew.net/support/wiki/HowtoLinksys

In order to RDP or access remote resources I found it necessary to disable Nat-T contrary to the posted instructions. Other than that the only change I made was I did not enable WINS server. I can RDP to internal machines, ping the internal resources and access them by IP.

Shrew is an excellent VPN client.I intend to set it up this week for another guy who has a Netgear FVX538 v2. The Prosafe client does not work under Vista or Win 7 x64 and Shrew works just dandy.