# Linksys RV042 and QuickVPN fails

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I've got a RV042 in the office.  It's already got some site to site VPNs setup through other gateways and I'm trying to a simple remote user's VPN access.  I tried using QuickVPN, adding a user to VPN Client Access, copying over the cert, forwarding 443,500,4500,60443 TCP/UDP on a test remote (in the same office, using a hotspot to get outside)'s NAT (and when this didn't work, made it DMZ, with the same lack of results).

Test machine is Win7.
Windows Firewall is on. No other firewalls present beyond the NAT.
IPSec Policy Agent is running.
Added a ICMPv4 Echo rule to the firewall.

On the RV042:
Block WAN Requests is off.
HTTPS is on.
I have a user added, it's connecting at least long enough to check the cert.

RV042's logs on connection:

```
Jan 17 15:24:39 2014         Authentication Success     HTTP Basic authentication succeeded for user: justin
```

QuickVPN's log.txt:

```
2014/01/17 15:24:35 [STATUS]OS Version: Windows 7
2014/01/17 15:24:35 [STATUS]Windows Firewall Domain Profile Settings: ON
2014/01/17 15:24:35 [STATUS]Windows Firewall Private Profile Settings: ON
2014/01/17 15:24:35 [STATUS]Windows Firewall Private Profile Settings: ON
2014/01/17 15:24:35 [STATUS]One network interface detected with IP address 192.168.1.10
2014/01/17 15:24:35 [STATUS]Connecting...
2014/01/17 15:24:35 [DEBUG]Input VPN Server Address = x.x.136.6
2014/01/17 15:24:35 [STATUS]Connecting to remote gateway with IP address: x.x.136.6
2014/01/17 15:24:37 [STATUS]Remote gateway was reached by https ...
2014/01/17 15:24:37 [WARNING]Failed to connect.
2014/01/17 15:24:39 [STATUS]Remote gateway was reached by https ...
2014/01/17 15:24:39 [WARNING]Failed to connect.
2014/01/17 15:24:39 [WARNING]Failed to connect!
```

Help would be appreciated. I realize there are other posts attempting to do the same thing, however I have followed each in kind and found no solution that worked for me.  For reference: [How do I set up a simple VPN on a Linksys RV042?](https://superuser.com/questions/189091/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-vpn-on-a-linksys-rv042)
[Configuring Shrew VPN to access Linksys RV082/RV042](https://superuser.com/questions/101908/configuring-shrew-vpn-to-access-linksys-rv082-rv042)

Answer (score 0):

Firmware actual v.3 2.3

Just in case, these are the rules that need to be configured on the PCs running Windows 7. I found a Microsoft forum explanation on how to do so (remember that you need an inbound and an outbound rule):

Here is a quote on allowing this on the PC:

"Control Panel --> System and security --> Windows Firewall --> Advanced settings --> Inbound rules --> New rule --> custom rule

In Protocol and ports: Protocol: ICMPv4  on the same panel go to customize, choose "Specific ICMP types", check the box "echo request" next... next... and save it."

• http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7network/thread/5aff5f8d-f138-4c9a-8646-5b3a99f1cae6

**please not that you need to create and Inbound and Outbound rule.

Also, these are the usual troubleshooting steps for the QuickVPN problems with a Windows 7 PC:

• Uninstall the utility. 
• Reinstall it as an administrator. 
• Right click the shortcut and go to properties, compatibility and run in windows vista service pack 2. 
• If none of that worked boot the machine in safe mode and try from there.

solution